# Fetching previous month's average based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

I have 2 data frames, "eastern" containing the auction data for certain dates and the other, "monthly_agg" containing the monthly average of those auctions.
I want to merge the data frames in a manner where the average auction for a said month will be the average auction price of the previous month.

For the eastern data frame,I have extracted the month and the year from the auction date and then concatenated the month-year to form a new column.

Eastern data-set:

```
    date       month  year   concat      
    2014-10-17 10     2014  10 - 2014   
    2014-10-24 10     2014  10 - 2014
    2014-10-31 10     2014  10 - 2014   
    2014-11-07 11     2014  11 - 2014   
    2014-11-17 11     2014  11 - 2014   
    2014-11-26 11     2014  11 - 2014   
    2014-12-26 12     2014  12 - 2014
    2015-01-22 1      2015  1-2015


For the monthly_agg data frame, I have calculated the monthly averages for the month-year combination.

monthly_agg data-set:

date       month year   concat      prev_avgL1
2014-10-17 10     2014  10 - 2014     avg10
2014-10-24 10     2014  10 - 2014     avg10
2014-10-31 10     2014  10 - 2014     avg10
2014-11-07 11     2014  11 - 2014     avg11
2014-11-17 11     2014  11 - 2014     avg11
2014-11-26 11     2014  11 - 2014     avg11
2014-12-26 12     2014  12 - 2014     avg12
2015-01-22 1      2015  1-2015        avg1(for the new year and new month)
```

Then using left_join() I have merged both the data-frames and created a new data-frame called eastern1.

After merging the data-frame "eastern1" has the following structure:

```
     date       concat      prev_avgL1
   >>2014-10-17 10 - 2014     avg10
   >>2014-10-24 10 - 2014     avg10
   >>2014-10-31 10 - 2014     avg10
   >>2014-11-07 11 - 2014     avg11
   >>2014-11-17 11 - 2014     avg11
   >>2014-11-26 11 - 2014     avg11
   >>2014-12-26 12 - 2014     avg12
    >>2015-01-22 1 -2015      avg1(for the new year and new month)

eastern$Date=as.Date(eastern$Date,format="%d-%m-%Y")
eastern$year=year(eastern$Date)
eastern$Month=month(eastern$Date)
eastern$concat=paste(eastern$Month,"-",eastern$year)

monthly_agg=aggregate( L1_BID_PRICE ~ Month+year , agg , mean )
monthly_agg$concat=paste(monthly_agg$Month,"-",monthly_agg$year)

eastern1=left_join(eastern,monthly_agg,by="concat")



The expected result should be :
            >date         concat      prev_avgL1
           >>2014-10-17   10 - 2014     NA
           >>2014-10-24   10 - 2014     NA
           >>2014-10-31   10 - 2014     NA
           >>2014-11-07   11 - 2014     avg10
           >>2014-11-17   11 - 2014     avg10
           >>2014-11-26   11 - 2014     avg10
           >>2014-12-26   12 - 2014     avg11
           >>2015-01-22    1 -2015      avg12...and so on

**Here the average for October is NA since the data-set has dates starting from October 2014. 


The actual result is after doing left_join():
        >date       concat      prev_avgL1
        >>2014-10-17 10 - 2014     avg10
       >>2014-10-24 10 - 2014     avg10
       >>2014-10-31 10 - 2014     avg10
       >>2014-11-07 11 - 2014     avg11
       >>2014-11-17 11 - 2014     avg11
       >>2014-11-26 11 - 2014     avg11
       >>2014-12-26 12 - 2014     avg12
       >>2015-01-22    1 -2015    avg1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be great if you could separate your input data from your attempted solution. I assume that the first data in your example code is an example of the "eastern" data frame? Could you please also provide a minimal example of the structure of "monthly_agg"? Thank you.

Comment: @chris, thanks for looking into it. I have updated the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the desired result by first subtracting a month from the dates via the `%m-%` function from the lubridate package before concatenating.

See documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/%25m%2B%25)

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

eastern <- data.frame(date = c("2014-10-17" , "2014-10-24", "2014-10-31", 
                               "2014-11-07", "2014-11-17", "2014-11-26", 
                               "2014-12-26", "2015-01-22", "2015-02-12")) %>%
           mutate(date = as.Date(date),
                  year = year(date %m-% months(1)),
                  month = month(date %m-% months(1)),
                  concat = paste(year, "-", month))

        date year month    concat
1 2014-10-17 2014     9  2014 - 9
2 2014-10-24 2014     9  2014 - 9
3 2014-10-31 2014     9  2014 - 9
4 2014-11-07 2014    10 2014 - 10
5 2014-11-17 2014    10 2014 - 10
6 2014-11-26 2014    10 2014 - 10
7 2014-12-26 2014    11 2014 - 11
8 2015-01-22 2014    12 2014 - 12
9 2015-02-12 2015     1  2015 - 1
```

If you join this with this (monthly_agg or aggs or whatever):

```
    avg    concat
1 avg10 2014 - 10
2 avg11 2014 - 11
3 avg12 2014 - 12
4  avg1  2015 - 1
5  avg2  2015 - 2
```

you'll get this

```
left_join(eastern[, c("date", "concat")], aggs, by = "concat")

        date    concat   avg
1 2014-10-17  2014 - 9  <NA>
2 2014-10-24  2014 - 9  <NA>
3 2014-10-31  2014 - 9  <NA>
4 2014-11-07 2014 - 10 avg10
5 2014-11-17 2014 - 10 avg10
6 2014-11-26 2014 - 10 avg10
7 2014-12-26 2014 - 11 avg11
8 2015-01-22 2014 - 12 avg12
9 2015-02-12  2015 - 1  avg1
```

Does that do it for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it partially worked for me but when the date is falling in the next year such as 2015-01-22,2016-01-15 etc then for left_join() makes the price column as blank. Please suggest how should I handle that.

Comment: You're right. I forgot about that one. I have corrected my comment.

Comment: Thanks so much, the update has worked but also a pointer here, that if the date is not continuous i.e. a month's gap, then the avg column has an NA value.